# Is it able to use EXT texture formats in opengl es 2.0?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, opentk

Now i have to rewrite my working OpenGL code to OpenGL ES2.0 (for ANGLE using). 
I use OpenTK and see EXT texture formats like OpenTK.Graphics.ES20.TextureComponentCount.R32fExt in "ES20" namespace. But when i try to use it i got an OpenGL error "InvalidEnum".

I need something like this (one channel, >= 16bit):

```
GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget2d.Texture2D, 0, OpenTK.Graphics.ES20.TextureComponentCount.R32fExt, 1296, 1296, 0, OpenTK.Graphics.ES20.PixelFormat.Red, PixelType.UnsignedShort, (IntPtr)dataPtr);
```

Is it able in ES2.0?

UPD: I need to attach that texture to framebuffer, so i cant use ALPHA or LUMINANCE format.

Comment: So how do you do it? How do you use EXT texture formats as parameters in OpenTK? Specifically, I want to use `GL.TexStorage3D` to allocate storage space for a cubemap array but `TextureTarget3d` doesn't have a cubemap array option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to run across a wide range of devices, you need runtime checks for the extensions you are using.

The general mechanism is that you get the extension string:

```
const GLubyte* extStr = glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);
```

and then check if the extension in question is part of this string. The list of all registered extensions can be found in the bottom section of the [OpenGL ES registry page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/) on www.khronos.org.

For example, to use float textures, the necessary extension is [OES_texture_float](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt). If the name of this extension is part of the extension string, you can use `GL_FLOAT` as a texture format. Note that ES 2.0 still uses unsized internal formats, so for a 1-component float texture you would use for example `GL_ALPHA` as the internal format, and `GL_FLOAT` as the type.

Comment: I need to attach that textures to framebuffer. I have some trouble with attaching GL_ALPHA or GL_LUMINANCE texture to FBO. GL_RED worked perfectly.